# Get coordinates of Z giving X,Y in Matlab

Tags: matlab, mesh

I have got some *meshgrids* with `x` `y` `z` with interpolation. I want to get `z` from each meshgrid with same `x` and `y`.
Ex. I want to know what is z value on `x=13` `y=0.20` for each meshgrid

```
[x y z]=meshgrid(x,y,z)
[x1 y1 z1]=meshgrid(x1,y1,z1)
[x2 y2 z2]=meshgrid(x2,y2,z2)

zOfxy=getz(13,0.20)
z1Ofx1y1=getz(13, 0.20)
z2Ofx2y2=getz(13, 0.20)
```

Is there any ready function? I know that I can plot it and get values form it but its very hard to get z accurate data

Comment: `[X Y Z]=meshgrid(x,y,z)` returns 3D arrays with  all values in the range of `z` for each value in `x` and `y`. Same for other permutations. If you are confused with what you are doing and what you want to do, read [`meshgrid`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html).

Comment: Are you after a sort of dictionary?

Comment: @erfan I didn't find anything useful in your link.

Comment: @Nic I don't understand your question

Comment: The meshgrid function returs a table of [x y z] values. For example: [x1 y1 z1; x2 y2 z2; .... xn yn zn ] .  What you want is a function returning z2 if you call getz(x2,y2). Is this correct? Alternatively, do you want to create a new 3d point for the x and y parameter?

Comment: I send you the link of official documentation of the function you are using and you do not find anything useful? Maybe you should also spend some more time on your questions.

Comment: @Nic yes, correct. I want to return z2 calling some function. Is there any ready function for this? I don't want to build function with double loop to search all the grid because this would be very much time-consuming.

Comment: Maybe, `interp2` or `interp3` is what you need?

Comment: @GarryMoveOut , I see what you mean. If you need a lookup, I believe there are no built-in functions you can use. However, the brute force approach should be O(n*m) , where n is the x cardinality and m is the y cardinality. Since both x and y values are sorted, you should easily do better than that.

Comment: If you just want a look-up table and not interpolation you can do it in O(1) as well, since this is a regular grid. You can use `interp3` as AVK mentioned if `(x,y)` is off the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built in function to retrieve all associated z values for a given x-y tuple. Since the arrays of X and Y values are sorted, you could use [Fibonacci search](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fibonacci-search/). Computational complexity should be *O*`(log n * log m)`, where n is the X cardinality and m is the Y cardinality.